# Can I dismiss a Notification Center Alert using the mouse?

Tags: macos, mouse, notifications

Is it possible to dismiss a sticky "alert" (from Notification Center) from the upper-right corner of the screen by using the mouse?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes!** You can simply click and drag the alert off to the right and it will disappear. If you have a multi-touch input device such as a trackpad, you can also use two fingers and swipe it away to the right.

Additionally, you can **temporarily move** the notification by **dragging it to the left**:

[image]

It will stay there for a few seconds and then move back to its original position. This currently seems very buggy, but perhaps it'll work better with future updates.