# Can I speed up the auto-dismissal of Notification Center banners?

Tags: notifications

I like Notification Center, but banners linger a bit too long before auto-dismissing.

I'm aware of [the popular two-finger swipe trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58071/can-i-dismiss-a-notification-center-alert-using-the-mouse) to immediately dismiss a banner, but I'm looking for an automated approach. Growl, for example, let you customize how long notifications stayed on the screen, but I don't see a similar option in the Notifications preference pane.

Is it possible to adjust this, like perhaps through a hidden preference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I never usually have any luck finding them, I used MacWorld's guide, "[How to find hidden preference settings](http://www.macworld.com/article/1135526/findhidden.html)", and I was able to find the hidden preference:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime <SECONDS>
```

Type the above into Terminal, replacing `<seconds>` with the number of seconds you want the banner to last for, and press <kbd>return</kbd>. Then, log out and log back in to reload Notification Center.

Comment: What is the default value? I think there is also a command to erase this setting as well?

Comment: @cwd The default is `5` seconds.