# macOS High Sierra Notification Center auto closing or not opening at all

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, trackpad, notifications

I had a problem before about my icons not displaying correctly, and I followed Orlando Castro's answer in this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8095249) at Apple Forums.

> In Menu > Go (press option) > Library > Preferences
>   Find and remove "com.apple.dock.extra.plist" and "com.apple.dock.plist" then restart.

After doing so I had no issue at all, but yesterday night I wanted to switch off "Night mode" which is located in Notification Center and for my surprise it didn't open at first with the gesture (Swipe left with 2 fingers from the right edge of trackpad), to make things worse I found that clicking on the Notification Center icon at the top right corner didn't make the Notification Center to be shown so I kept clicking on it for many times until it finally popped but it auto closed before I could turn night shift off.

Here's a video showing the issue: https://youtu.be/rU_Ph57dm8Y

I restarted my Mac and I'm still having this issue.

These are my Mac specs:

- MacBook Pro (13", 2016, four Thunderbolt 3 ports) (With Touch Bar)
- Processor: 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory: 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

From the suggested questions while writing this question I found this other question: [How do I re-enable Notification Center in Yosemite or El Capitan post-upgrade?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152064/how-do-i-re-enable-notification-center-in-yosemite-or-el-capitan-post-upgrade) which I thought could be the answer, but after running both commands:

> ```
> launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
> killall NotificationCenter
> ```

and restarting my Mac, the problem shown in the video above persists.

Also, in the suggested questions I found this other question: [Can I speed up the auto-dismissal of Notification Center banners?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64026/can-i-speed-up-the-auto-dismissal-of-notification-center-banners) because I thought it could be a problem related to the time it was too low, I switched it to 5 seconds, logged out and in after doing so, restarted my Mac and still no success.

As shown in the video, I can't get Notification Center to be shown while using gesture and sometimes I can do it while clicking Notification Center.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working with a chatbot with Dialogflow which wasn't responding correctly. Once I did 2 restarts and correct it, my notification bar is working again as expected.